# Add block to cart summary in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-block

How can i add custom text block into cart summary?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create layout file: `My\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <block name="summary.custom.block" class="My\Module\Block\Cart\CustomBlock"  template="cart/custom_block.phtml" before="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```